# Swift classes not found in iOS app when importing a mixed framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a framework with `Objective-C` and `Swift` mixed together. It compiles alone but when I import it in the `Objective-C` iOS app, `Swift` classes are not found but `Objective-C` classes are found.
My Swift classes are found inside the framework when importing `MyFramework-Swift.h`
The `iOS` app and framework are two different projects in the same workspace.

`Defines Module` and `Embedded content contains Swift Code` are set to `Yes` for all targets and my `Swift` classes are public with `@objc`

I tried to use `@import MyFramework` and `#import <MyFramework/MyFramework-Swift.h>` with no success.

I don't see the `MyFramework-Swift.h` header file in the framework's Headers directory into the projects. Not sure if this is normal. It is generated in `DerivedData`

EDIT: I managed to reproduce the problem with a very simple workspace in Xcode 8 (but probably the same in 7.3):

- Create a new Cocoa touch framework `TestFramework` in objective-C
- Create a `A.h` file

  ```
  @class B;

  @interface A : NSObject

  -(void)print:(B*)caller;

  @end
  ```
- Create a `A.m` file

  ```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
  #import "TestFramework-Swift.h"

  #import "A.h"

  @implementation A

  -(void)print:(B*)caller {
      [caller test];
  }
  ```
- Create a `B.swift` file

  ```
  import Foundation

  @objc public class B : NSObject {
      public func test() {
          print("test");
      }
  }
  ```
- Set `A.h` as a public header
- import `A.h` into `TestFramework.h`
- Try to compile the framework

Here the `TestFramework-Swift.h` is not found

- Set `Install Objective-C compatibility header` to `No`
- Try to compile the framework

Now it compiles !

- Create a new iOS Objective-C Single view application App
- Update the ViewController.m like this

  ```
   #import "ViewController.h"
   @import TestFramework;

   @interface ViewController ()

   @end

   @implementation ViewController

   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       B* b = [[B alloc] init];
       A* a = [[A alloc] init];
       [a print: b];
   }
  [...]
  @end
  ```

You should have an error on B but not A. I also set `Defines Module` to `Yes` in both project without success

Comment: A few questions: 1) Are the framework and the Objective-C code actually different projects, or just different targets in the same project?  It sounds like they are in different projects, but wanted to double-check.  2) What kind of Objective-C code uses the framework?  Is it a command-line utility? A Cocoa app? A library?

Comment: 1) They are different projects in the same workspace. 2) It is an iOS application Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer. `Install Objective-C compatibility header` must be set to `Yes` and the import must be `#import <TestFramework/TestFramework-Swift.h>`and not `#import "TestFramework-Swift.h"` inside the framework